# Perl Insert Trademark Symbol into Mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, pdf, character-encoding, dbi

I wrote a perl script that uses the CAM PDF module to extract PDF metadata from pdf files. I then take that data and insert it into MySQL using DBI. I ran across a PDF file that contains special characters. I can confirm the MySQL schema and DB table are set to UTF8. I have the perl script set to use utf8 by `use utf8;` I also have the DBI connection set to use this `mysql_enable_utf8 => 1`.

I can now save some of the symbols (Copyright, Registered) but the Trademark symbol gets converted into an apostrophe/accent. I read that setting `$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8')` would help solve this but with my scenario it cuts all the text after the first encounter of a symbol.

I'm guessing the issue is the text coming from the PDF is set in another encoding format and not UTF8. I tried to decode/encode those strings using `use Encoding` module and that converts the symbols to text. When that text is outputted to a web page using php it displays as text and not as the symbol.

Comment: Sounds like you've got data being rendered out as ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1252 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: `use utf8` only states that your script is encoded in utf-8. It doesn't do anything else. For further information see the `perldoc` pages `utf8` and `perlunicode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to `use utf8` being not relevant here... [PDF metadata use special PDFDocEncoding](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) (or UTF-16BE, if PDFDocEncoding is not enough, but that's not your case), where **trademark** is decimal 146 -- which is **quoteright** in CP1252, that's what you get. Because [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/module/CAM%3a%3aPDF) doesn't do any decoding (neither [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/module/PDF%3a%3aAPI2), btw) and returns raw bytes. You have to decode them yourself. But, for simple task of metadata extraction, you can use [Image::ExifTool](https://metacpan.org/release/Image-ExifTool), it says it decodes from PDFDocEncoding automatically.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Image::ExifTool. This solved my encoding issues perfectly.